# Parse datetime with offset string to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, json, date, java-time

I am trying to parse following datetime String to LocalDateTimeObject, however I am not able to identify the format of the datetime string.

**`Sat, 09 Oct 2021 02:10:23 -0400`**

```
    String s = "Sat, 09 Oct 2021 02:10:23 -0400";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(s, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

How should I determine the pattern of the above string?

Comment: Your string contains an offset, so using `LocalDateTime` is not the right tool. In any case, your string doesn't conform to the ISO-8601 format, so you shouldn't try to use to use the format `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check if the date string matches any of the [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#:%7E:text=Predefined%20Formatters,05%3A30%20GMT%27).

If not, then you have to make your own `Formatter` using `.ofPattern(String pattern)` or `.ofPattern(String pattern, Locale locale)`. To do this, you can see all the defined pattern letters [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#:%7E:text=Symbol%20%20Meaning%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Presentation%20%20%20%20%20%20Examples) in section *Patterns for Formatting and Parsing*.

For your example, you can use either `DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(s, formatted);
```

or:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(s, formatted);
```

Note that `OffsetDateTime` is used to represent the date-time with an offset from UTC.

---

```
 Symbol  Meaning       
 ------  -------        
   E     day-of-week 
   d     day-of-month
   M     month-of-year
   y     year-of-era
   H     hour-of-day (0-23)
   m     minute-of-hour
   s     second-of-minute
   Z     zone-offset
```

Comment: How do I represent the time zone in the pattern, If I understand correctly, the '-0400' in the Date String stands for GMT -4, also evident from the documentation of the API which is returning the date mentions  "Important: The Timezone of all news are displayed is Eastern Timezone (GMT -0400)."